strange linear relationship between regression coefficient and intercept in cross sectional data
I have a dataset that has a timeseries and a cross sectional element.
y(t, j) is the y value at time t belonging to company j.
x(t, j) is the x value at time t belonging to company j.
For a fixed time t I run a regression cross-sectionally:
y(tfix, j) = a_tfix + b_tfix * x(tfix, j) + ej
I repeat the above cross-sectional regression and I collect all the a_tfix, and b_tfix.
Then I make a scatterplot of a_tfix versus b_tfix and observe a strong linear relationship with an R2 of 0.98.
i.e. the coefficients b are strongly dependent on the overall level of the data a.
Does anybody have a suggestion of what to do with this data?
Table below shows a couple of rows with the regression output:

The figure below shows the scatter plot when I plot the a and the b:

Any idea of "best practises" when dealing with this type of data?
Should I standardize the y and x such that it becomes comparable cross time periods? Or is it best practise to leave the data as is?
I am not expecting that there exist 1 perfect solution, but just trying to get an idea of how people better at statistics would deal with this.

It may be instructive for answerers here to provide the aforementioned scatterplot so that we can see what is going on and what may be causing the issue.

thanks, i have added the scatter plot and also a couple of rows from the table.

"Does anybody have a suggestion of what to do with this data?" What is your aim? By the way, for understanding the strong connection between a and b, I'd look at scatterplots for a number of fixed time points with different levels of (a,b) separately to see what is going on.

What kind of values do the x(tfix,.) take? Do these change much for different tfix? Also, it looks like the b-values are bounded from below by zero, maybe also the a-values. Does this just happen "by accident", or did you do anything to constrain these values?

To give more context:
Every month i collect the bondspreads (y) and a risk measure (x). The bond spreads are in theory >0. The risk metric is a number between 0 and 100.
I run a linear regression: spread = a +b*risk_metric
The b should be positive in theory --> riskier bonds have higher spreads.
I could run a cross sectional regression like above every month and see how bondspreads relate to their risk measure.
But there seems to be a lot of "structure" in the data, and i was wondering if there was a smarter / better way to analyze this data.

I didn't do anything to constrain the raw data (spreads and risk measure). But economic theory kind of bounds it between certain values.
What I get from the scatter plot is that when a is big, i.e. the general level of spreads is high (i.e. markets are risky). Then the market is also more sensitive to changes in risk measure (higher b).

So you are saying a good number of b coefficients in your plot look exactly zero by accident? (OK, maybe they are not exactly zero, just very close to it.) Observing such a number of zero values of a measurement that should be positive but isn't constrained to be seems odd.  How exactly did you compute the a and b? Is there some reason why by definition the risk measure is related to spreads in such a way that the slope b must be nonnegative? Just because of random variation I'd expect occasionally negative values in such a situation if there isn't any constraint enforced.

i used the plain vanilla OLS to compute a and b. It was inside the statsmodels package in python.
It is expected that riskier bonds have higher spreads. But it is not a 'law'. Because the risk measure might not be perfect. So yes, it could happen that we observe negative values.
In fact for a different sector i did the same and we observed a bunch of negative b.
